# Which dependencies are removable after building ruby?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ruby, package-management

I've successfully built ruby `2.1.1` on Ubuntu/Debian by installing the following dependencies:

```
apt-get install \
  autoconf \
  bison \
  build-essential \
  libssl-dev \
  libyaml-dev \
  libreadline6 \
  libreadline6-dev \
  zlib1g \
  zlib1g-dev
```

After the build want to remove packages I don't need anymore as I'm trying to keep this image as small as possible.

Which of these (if any) can I remove after the build? Is there a heuristic for this?

Comment: Generally, `-dev` packages are source code so they can be removed if you don't plan to compile anything else that uses them.  However, you also need to make sure that you won't be building any more Ruby Gems (directly or via Bundler), because some gems use these libraries too.